Postman/SoapUI SOAP service call results BadContextToken
I've read a ridiculous amount of content to try to fix this but nothing seems to work. I know the server is set up and working fine so it's not a timeout. I have to be missing something within the post call. I get the same issue in soapui whith ws-a setup. I get the same error no matter what I send as long as the call has a body tag. Otherwise I get a 400.
I have a working web service sitting on IIS. The service uses a user/pass which I am sending as basic auth. When I take the WSDL into c# I can make working calls. However if I call the web service on IIS directly using postman or soapui, I get this:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
                <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">a:BadContextToken</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
        </s:Code>
        <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.</s:Text>
        </s:Reason>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

I inspected the headers from the c# code to see what I may be missing and compared it to the WSDL import on postman and soapui. I did see postman was missing a few things and tried adding them with no change.
Here is the body of the post
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <tem:G4TLogin/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Here is the security portion of the WSDL
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_ISMSXMLWebService_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
<sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:BootstrapPolicy>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:TransportBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
<sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:UsernameToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
<sp:Wss11>
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:BootstrapPolicy>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SecureConversationToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
<sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

Here is what I'm attempting in postman

Here is the captured info from a working outgoing call from c#

and finally here is the document that shows how to write the c# code for the login, ignore the .tolower

